# unit-test search method (querydsl) with mockito

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, querydsl, entitymanager

In my springboot app I'm trying to write a unit test for my search method using mockito:

Service:

```java
QRental qRental = QRental.rental;
        var jpaQuery = new JPAQuery<Rental>(entityManager)
                .select(qRental)
                .from(qRental);


        if (reason != null && !reason.isBlank()) {
            jpaQuery = jpaQuery.where(qRental.reason.likeIgnoreCase(reason));
        }

        var result = jpaQuery.fetch();
        return rentalMapper.toDtos(result);
```

Test:

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class RentalServiceImplTest {

    
    @Mock
    private JPAQuery<Rental> jpaQuery;


    @Mock
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Mock
    private QRental qRental;

    @InjectMocks
    private RentalServiceImpl rentalService;

    @Test
    void searchRentals() {


        when(jpaQuery.select()).thenReturn(new JPAQuery<>());
        when(jpaQuery.from()).thenReturn(new JPAQuery<>());
        when(jpaQuery.where()).thenReturn(new JPAQuery<>());

do more stuff...
```

And i get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory.getProperties()" because the return value of "javax.persistence.EntityManager.getEntityManagerFactory()" is null

    at com.querydsl.jpa.impl.JPAProvider.getTemplates(JPAProvider.java:94)
    at com.querydsl.jpa.impl.JPAQuery.<init>(JPAQuery.java:48)
```

I think the problem has to do with the EntityManager initialization, but Im not 100% sure.
Can anyone help??? If more info is required, I'm happy to provide :)
Thanks in advance!!!

I want to mock querydsl used in RentalServiceImpl, in order for it to return a predefined list of rental entities for the test.

Comment: since its a NPE thats mean that your test has instantiated correctly and there is an exception related to injecting or mocking   data so can you debug and tell us in which line the exception accrued

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, mocking DB API is not an effective approach to testing DB queries.

- you rely heavily on DB Access library internals
- you are not likely to find any syntax errors

Instead, you should:

- configure your tests to start up a DB on your machine. Ideally, use same engine that you use on PROD.
- This can be embedded DB, or run in Docker
- You can fall back to H2, which is the quickest to set up, but differences from your PROD engine will eventually bite you.
- Use Spring-Boots `DataJpaTest` to test your Data Access component against this DB
- Note that DataJpaTest uses H2 by default, configure your test to disable this behaviour

For testing your service methods, mocking entire repository component is a good approach.

And for your original question:

Look at the implementation of [JPAProvider.getTemplates](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/blob/master/querydsl-jpa/src/main/java/com/querydsl/jpa/impl/JPAProvider.java#L94)

```java
// detect by properties
for (String key : em.getEntityManagerFactory().getProperties().keySet()) {
    key = key.toLowerCase();
    for (Map.Entry<String, JPQLTemplates> entry : templatesByName.entrySet()) {
        if (key.contains(entry.getKey())) {
            return entry.getValue();
        }
    }
}
```

Most likely hou are missing a stub for one of methods in `em.getEntityManagerFactory().getProperties().keySet()` chain, thus Mockito  returns default value, which is null.